# return 0 if a value is null

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL query in my php script, which is working fine currently. The only issue I have is that some of the columns return null values.

If there is data for those columns then they return the value, but if there is no data or records for the date then they return null. All I want to do is modify this query so that if anything is null it returns '0'.

I'm not sure if I should use IFNULL or coalesce but either way I'm unfamiliar with the best way to apply it to this query.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
$stmt3 = mysqli_prepare($conn2,
     "UPDATE ambition.ambition_totals a
        INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT 
            c.user AS UserID,
            COUNT(*) AS dealers,
            ROUND((al.NumberOfDealers / al.NumberOfDealerContacts) * 100 ,2)  AS percent
        FROM jfi_dealers.contact_events c
        JOIN jackson_id.users u
        ON c.user = u.id
        JOIN jfi_dealers.dealers d
        ON c.dealer_num = d.dealer_num
        LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS NumberOfDealerContacts,
          SUM(CASE WHEN ( d.next_call_date + INTERVAL 7 DAY) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumberOfDealers
          FROM jackson_id.attr_list AS al
          JOIN jfi_dealers.dealers AS d ON d.csr = al.data
          WHERE al.attr_id = 14
          GROUP BY user_id) AS al
        ON al.user_id = c.user
        GROUP BY UserID) as cu
        on cu.UserID = a.ext_id 
        SET a.dealers_contacted = cu.dealers,
          a.percent_up_to_date = cu.percent;
                ") or die(mysqli_error($conn2));
```

UPDATE

Version with IFNULL statment:

```
UPDATE ambition.ambition_totals a
        INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT 
            c.user AS UserID,
            ifnull(count(*),0) AS dealers,
            ifnull(ROUND((al.NumberOfDealers / al.NumberOfDealerContacts) * 100 ,2),0)  AS percent
        FROM jfi_dealers.contact_events c
        JOIN jackson_id.users u
        ON c.user = u.id
        JOIN jfi_dealers.dealers d
        ON c.dealer_num = d.dealer_num
        LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS NumberOfDealerContacts,
          SUM(CASE WHEN ( d.next_call_date + INTERVAL 7 DAY) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumberOfDealers
          FROM jackson_id.attr_list AS al
          JOIN jfi_dealers.dealers AS d ON d.csr = al.data
          WHERE al.attr_id = 14
          GROUP BY user_id) AS al
        ON al.user_id = c.user
        WHERE c.created_at >= CURDATE()
        GROUP BY UserID) as cu
        on cu.UserID = a.ext_id 
        SET a.dealers_contacted = cu.dealers,
          a.percent_up_to_date = cu.percent;
```

Comment: You can always change the NULL value in 0 in php after you execute the query, are you able to provide the rest of the php code?

Comment: MySQL's  IF function will do just fine... `IF([column] IS NULL, 0, [colomn])`

Comment: @RaymondNijland I'm using the IFNULL statement from MySQL syntax, as shown in my update above but it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [IFNULL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) for this. But be very sure that you actually want this behaviour. PHP is also familiar with NULL values and can handle them just fine. 0 has a very different meaning. But if you do want this behaviour, simply wrap the field or statement that might return null in a IFNULL, for example:

```
SELECT IFNULL(user_id, 0);
```

But you can also do this in PHP itself, so you do not have to modify the query:

```
if (is_null($result['field'])) {
  echo 0;
}
```

Or, if you use PHP 7+, you can also use the [null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op):

```
echo $result['field'] ?? 0;
```

Comment: This is probably a dumb question, but would I use 'field' in the php code? Or the name of each individual field (i.e. userID, dealers, etc.)

Comment: Use the actual field name, so userID, dealers etc. And instead of `$result`, use the actual variable in which you store the result of your sql query (So whatever variable you store the execute result of `$stmt3` in).

Comment: ```mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt3) or die(mysqli_error($conn2));
if (is_null($stmt3['dealers'])) {
  echo 0;
}``` Is not working, it's telling me it can't use the object of type mysqli_stmt as array

Comment: I'm using the first line to execute and then using the if statement right after

Comment: You need to store the executed statement result in a variable of it's own. `$stmt3` just holds the statement, not the results once it's executed. Also see example #3 on http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php .. you still need to `fetch()` the results afterwards.